# Generate names for nested element

Tags: grammar, xtext

I have a grammar like this:

```
Entity:
    'entity' name=ID '{'
        (properties+=Property)*

        (revision=Revision)?
    '}'

Revision:
    'revision' '{'
        (properties+=Property)+
    '}'
```

The editor gives me lots of errors for the revisions because they don't have a name. Since a revision is always a child of Entity, can I assign it a name automatically? Something like `name=this.parent.name + "_REV"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to extend `DefaultDeclarativeQualifiedNameProvider`:

```
import org.eclipse.xtext.naming.DefaultDeclarativeQualifiedNameProvider;
import org.eclipse.xtext.naming.QualifiedName;
import model.Revision;

public class ModelQualifiedNameProvider extends DefaultDeclarativeQualifiedNameProvider {

    public final static String REVISION_TABLE_EXTENSION = "_REV";
    public final static String REVISION_TYPE_EXTENSION = "Rev";

    public QualifiedName qualifiedName( Revision obj ) {
        QualifiedName qn = getFullyQualifiedName( obj.eContainer() );

        String typeName = qn.getLastSegment() + REVISION_TABLE_EXTENSION;

        QualifiedName result = qn.skipLast( 1 );
        result = result.append( typeName );

        return result;
    }

}
```

Make sure you get the method signature right! Xtext reflectively invokes `QualifiedName qualifiedName(MyType ele)` and if you upgrade from 1.0 to 2.0, don't forget to update the signature: Change the return type from `String` to `QualifiedName`